# URL Not Defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/allmyfindstest.html) page, but I'm receiving an error that I'm not sure how to resolve.

The error I receive in firefox is 'downloadURL is not defined' and it highlights this line as being the problem:

```
downloadUrl("loadallmyfinds.php", function(data) {
```

This page did work correctly until I added this JS function,

```
(function reversegeocode() {
```

so it's obvious that the problem lies within the introduction of this.

But I've gone through the script a number of times now, and I just can't find the problem. I've checked the php script and I know that the correct information is being retrieved from the mySQL database. Having used this type of file before, I've also checked that the parsing of the xml is correct in terms of format etc.

I must admit to being fairly new to javscript, so perhaps my lack of knowledge is letting me down.

I just wondered though whether someone could perhaps take a look at this please and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Many thanks

Comment: Your indentation is really messed up. Hard to read the code, but the error happens because the downloadUrl function is not avaiable when it's called. Is it defined in a closure or something?

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking a look at my post. I've changed the indentation, so I hope it's easier to read, apologies. As far as a relatively newcomer can tell, the 'downloadURL' isn't part of a closure. Kind regards

Comment: You're welcome. I don't have time to look into this now, but try moving the function declaration to the top or something. Make sure it is available in the scope where it is called from :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's where your downloadUrl is declared:

```
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
       var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

       request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request.responseText, request.status);
            }
       };

       request.open('GET', url, true);
       request.send(null);
}
//two other functions elided

})   // <------ what's this?!
```

It looks like your declaring this function inside of another scope, which means it's not globally available, like your code assumes it is.  This is likely why you're getting the undeclared error

**EDIT**

I moved your downloadUrl function to the very **top** of the script, and you no longer get this error.  Unfortunately you now get an error about doNothing being undefined.

You just need to load all this JavaScript into a JavaScript-friendly IDE (so not Visual Studio) and really untangle all these braces and parenthesis, so you can figure out where your unwanted scope is.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for looking at this for me. I had used the geocode script before and tried to adapt. However I've taken the section you suggest out of the script and unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. Have you anymore ideas please?

Comment: Hi Adam, many thanks for your continued help. I think you might be on the same lines as @dzejkej, unless I've misunderstood. Regards

Comment: Hi Adam, please see my last comment to dzejkej. I think I need to look at this first rather than wasting your time having to trawl through my code. Kind regards

Comment: @IRHM: Yes, you are right - just make sure you have the function definition first and function call later. You can do it Adam's way or mine - same result :).

Comment: @dzejkej - assuming you're defining the function in the form:  funcion downloadUrl(... (which OP is) then it **doesn't matter** whether it's called before it's defined.  Function definitions are **hoisted** to the top of the scope.  It's only if you do something like `var downloadUrl = function() {` that the definition of the function would not be hoisted (just the declaration)  OP's problem is that he's has one or two too many braces or parens such that his scope is getting screwed up; his downloadUrl function is not defined in the scope that he thinks it is

Comment: @IRHM - the other answer is definitely pointing out some valid points about your code, but note that you do **not** have to define a function before you call it.  Assuming you declare the function in the form `function blah()` as opposed to `var blah = function()` than its definition will be hoisted to the top of the context.  Check out this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/UUNZV/

Comment: @AdamRackis Thanks for useful information! I will add your comment into my answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Take the whole call of `downloadUrl()`:

```
downloadUrl("loadallmyfinds.php", function(data) { 
  // .. rest of the function ..
});
```

... and move it to the bottom of the `load()` function, below `doNothing() {}`.

Also make sure you are using [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) or [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to check your code for errors. You have some errors there. Several widely used editors/IDEs have support for those tool. Or you can use [Cloud9 IDE](http://c9.io) as a free web-based IDE with support for error-checking.

Also fix this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(gmarker, function() {
  updateMarkerAddress; // <- this is a function and you are not calling it
});
```

**EDIT:**

Very useful comment from **Adam Rackis** addressing my lack of knowledge about hoisting (see comments below *his* answer):

> Assuming you're defining the function in the form: function `downloadUrl() {...}` (which OP is) then it doesn't matter whether it's called before it's defined. Function definitions are hoisted to the top of the scope. It's only if you do something like `var downloadUrl = function() { ... }` that the definition of the function would not be hoisted (just the declaration).

Comment: Hi, sorry for asking a really dumb question, but do you mean just this line or the whole section which ends document.getElementById('findosgb36lon').value = this.formfindosgb36lon; Kind regards.

Comment: @IRHM Move whole function call (all that big chunk of code :) ) and put it below the `doNothing()` function definition. I updated my answer. Hope it is clear now :).

Comment: Hi, I've done that, but unfortunately none of my markers appear on the map. Yourself and @Adam have both suggested I take a closer look at my code format. I think that what I need to do is go away and do this without wasting anymore of yours or Adams' time. I'll let you know how I get on. Kind regards